# Do muscles deform bones?

Tags: exercise, muscle, bones

I remember reading about bones can have their shape deformed by muscles pulling on them.

[also this website suggets](https://www.google.com/amp/s/theconversation.com/amp/what-exercise-does-to-your-bones-57524) that bones along the shaft get wider and thicker

> These forces squash, twist and bend bones. The shin bone briefly becomes nearly a millimetre shorter as your foot hits the ground when running. The bone senses these small changes, and can grow dramatically – in the months after starting exercise – in order to reduce the risk of breaking. For example, the racket arm bones of tennis players can be 20% wider and contain 40% more bone mineral than their other arm, while sprint runners have up to a third more bone in their shin bone than people who don’t exercise.

therefore this should explain the logic and reasoning behind my question now;

Can training the muscles attached to the ribs, cause the bones to be pulled out and deformed, resulting in a wider ribcage skeletal structure and not only a bigger V taper due to larger latissimus dorsi?  Like when pulling for a pull up, can the muscle pull outwards on the ribs and deform them?

also this website suggests that [natural lifters can build up to 5 kilograms of muscle for each kilogram of bone](https://www.strongerbyscience.com/your-drug-free-muscle-and-strength-potential-part-1/)

and since bones have the ability to adapt either losing density and size due to lack of exercise as seen with elderly and astronauts or become denser and larger with training.  Does this mean that muscle growth can be limitless as long as bones gets stronger?

Comment: Do muscles deform bones or do the *forces applied* while training deform bones?